# How to programmatically hide/disable emoticons on Android soft keyboard

Tags: android, android-edittext, android-softkeyboard

Is it possible to hide a specific keyboard button? I have an `EditText` and on some devices its keyboard has smiley faces while on other devices it is missing. I want to hide it on all devices.

Below is the XML for my `EditText`:

```
android:id="@+id/text_editor"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_alignWithParentIfMissing="true"
android:layout_centerVertical="true"
android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/send_side"
android:hint="Enter your text"
android:imeOptions="actionSend|flagNoEnterAction"
android:inputType="textLongMessage|textAutoCorrect|textCapSentences|textMultiLine"
android:maxLength="1000"
android:maxLines="3"
android:nextFocusRight="@+id/send_button"
android:padding="12dp"
android:textSize="13sp"
```

Is this possible?

Comment: No, as far as I know you cannot selectively hide keyboard buttons. Setting the inputType is all you can do but its up to the keyboard apps what they do with the inputType.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I found something in "[Disabling smiley key on keyboards with the stock messaging app in ICS](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/20601/disabling-smiley-key-on-keyboards-with-the-stock-messaging-app-in-ics)".

You need to remove the `textLongMessage` option from the `inputType`.

You will still have the ":-)" button on most keyboards, but not the emoji.

Comment: Any other way to even hide that also??

Answer (score 10):

(For completeness sake)

This solution is for people who need to have textview without the smiley on their soft keyboard. @Adrian's solution, to use email address type, works but it will show unnecessary '@' and '.com' buttons on your keyboard. I tried several combinations of InputType and the best solution IMHO is this:

```
mTextView.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_TEXT | InputType.TYPE_TEXT_VARIATION_VISIBLE_PASSWORD);
```

Original Keyboard:

[image]

Resulting keyboard:

[image]

Comment: this removes textAutoCorrect and textCapSentences functionality

Comment: It is working with portrait mode. In landscape mode, Emoji button is showing me

Comment: Worked for me, Thanks

Comment: Be careful of not only it disables auto-suggestion, but it also hides the switch language completely. Also internationalization character in email address are permitted by RFC 6530.

Comment: In xml ```android:inputType="textVisiblePassword"```

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me on Android 4.4.2

```
android:inputType="textEmailAddress|textMultiLine"
```

Comment: @HopefullyHelpful Did you find the answer? It is not working for me too in android 5

Answer (score 1):

From Petr Daña in a similar question... This enables autocomplete and disables all the smileys.

```
InputFilter filter = new InputFilter() {
@Override
public CharSequence filter(CharSequence source, int start, int end, Spanned dest, int dstart, int dend) {
    for (int i = start; i < end; i++) {
        int type = Character.getType(source.charAt(i));
        //System.out.println("Type : " + type);
        if (type == Character.SURROGATE || type == Character.OTHER_SYMBOL) {
            return "";
        }
    }
    return null;
    }
};

mMessageEditText.setFilters(new InputFilter[]{filter});
```

Refer to "[How to detect emoticons in EditText in android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31041802/how-to-detect-emoticons-in-edittext-in-android/31048120#31048120)".

Answer (score 0):

I tried @Adrian's solution, but it has "@" and ".com" keys. I just need a field that can take user's name. I got my solution by combining `textVisiblePassword` and `textNoSuggestions`:

```
android:inputType="textVisiblePassword|textNoSuggestions"
```

Comment: If a password manager is installed on the Android device it will show a pop on any field marked as "textVisiblePassword". I saw this on an Android 8 device and the app "Keypass2Android".

Answer (score -1):

```
mEditText.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_TEXT | InputType.TYPE_TEXT_VARIATION_VISIBLE_PASSWORD| TEXT_MULTILINE);
```

Comment: Please provide some context for this code snippet, and perhaps some explanation of why it improves on the other answers posted over the last 6 years.

Comment: TYPE_TEXT_VARIATION_VISIBLE_PASSWORD - We use Password char as Text input for EditTest. It doesn't have emojis and email keys like .com and @ keys
TEXT_MULTILINE - This will change the keyboard layout button [Done] or [->] to [Enter]  key so we can use multi line text or new line feature.