# How to detect emoticons in EditText in android

Tags: android, android-edittext, detect, emoticons

I want to detect whether my `EditText` contains smilie (emoticons) or not. But I have no idea that how to detect them.

Comment: by similes I mean emoticons.

Comment: Have you tried typing emoticons in the edittext and see what text it contains with EditText.getText()

Answer (score 23):

To disable emoji characters when typing on the keyboard I using the following filter:

```
InputFilter filter = new InputFilter() {
    @Override
    public CharSequence filter(CharSequence source, int start, int end, Spanned dest, int dstart, int dend) {
        for (int i = start; i < end; i++) {
            int type = Character.getType(source.charAt(i));
            //System.out.println("Type : " + type);
            if (type == Character.SURROGATE || type == Character.OTHER_SYMBOL) {
                return "";
            }
        }
        return null;
    }
};

mMessageEditText.setFilters(new InputFilter[]{filter});
```

If you need only detect if EditText contains any emoji character you can use this priciple (`Character.getType()`) in `android.text.TextWatcher` interface implementation (in `onTextChange()` or `afterTextChanged()` method) or e.g. use simple `for` cycle on `mMessageEditText.getText()` (returns CharSequence class) with `charAt()` method.

Comment: this is really help full.

Comment: But if using the filter, there is another bug that will exist. First type something, then enter emoji, then press back space, 2 characters will be deleted instead of 1

Comment: Nice, but sadly, this also excludes a lot of other special characters like © ® ™ ℅, Chinese symbols and even the tactile alphabet.

Comment: You may also would like to add more character types to this method, like Character.ENCLOSING_MARK, Character.MATH_SYMBOL, Character.OTHER_PUNCTUATION, Character.DASH_PUNCTUATION, Character.MIN_RADIX

Answer (score 1):

If by `simile` you are referring to the figure of speech, you can use `.getText()` and the `String` method `.contains(String)` to check whether it contains the Strings "like" or "as".

Snippet:

```
EditText myEditText = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.myEditText);
String input = myEditText.getText();
if(input.contains("like") || input.contains("as"))
{
    //code
}
```

Comment: by similes I mean emoticons.

Comment: I think you mean smilies.  A simile is something completely different

Comment: I extremly sorry for that  but now i corrected the question

Answer (score -2):

It depends the way you are implementing simleys in your edittext. if you are using motioons you can do this using a trick. You can set a condtion whenever a simpley a added you can add some type of keyword to arrayList and whenever smiley is remover you can remove that keyword from arrayList. And at last you can check that list whether that simley is added to it or not by processing the arrayList items.

for ex...

```
if(Smiley_added){
arraylist.add(smiley_code,i);
}

if(simley_removed){
arraylist.remove(smileycode,i);
}

if(arraylist.get(i).equals("smileyCode")){
do this....
}
```

Comment: I want want to detect if emoticons are present or not ,and then on sending to server i want to remove them so how large can be the map of similes and also this method will be hardcoded if i check for every emoticons via building a map of emoticons vs code.