# Android :prevent EditText from rendering Emoji

Tags: android, unicode, android-edittext, emoji

What I need is to stop edittext from Rendering system default Emojis 
and use my own emojis with the same rendering way ( unicodes ) , so I DONT to FILTER the Text so it wont pass the text between a range so that emojis wont show up and I just don't know which method to override or remove from default EditText to stop this rendering . the casue I need to do this is that whenever I want to render my own emojis it will first be rendered to system default emojis and quickly changes the span to mine and this isn't nice 
if I use filters then I wont be able to enter any emojis with Unicode so filtering by emoji Unicode range is not the ANSWER !

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to disable emoji from being entered in Android EditText?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22990870/how-to-disable-emoji-from-being-entered-in-android-edittext)

Comment: @NickTitov Its not , I don't wanna use filters and solutions there are just all using filters . read my question then comment out .

Answer (score 0):

in EditText xlm set attribute

```
app:emojiCompatEnabled="false"
```

it will stop render emoji by AppCompat

Comment: no working in AutoCompleteTextView