# How do I Hide the option for displaying Smileys on Default Samsung keyboard programmatically?

Tags: android, xamarin.android, android-softkeyboard

There is a requirement for not allowing to display the option of Smileys on the Android soft keyboard. We are testing this on 2 different types of keyboards :

1. Gboard
2. Default Samsung keyboard

Scenario 1: On **Gboard** I do not see the option for displaying Smileys : **This is expected**

[image]

Scenario 2: On **default Samsung keyboard**, I can still see the option for displaying Smileys : **Not expected**

[image]

Below are the few solutions which I have tried : mEditText.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_TEXT | InputType.TYPE_TEXT_VARIATION_VISIBLE_PASSWORD| TEXT_MULTILINE);

and

android:inputType="textEmailAddress"

from here : [How to disable emoji from being entered in Android EditText?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22990870/how-to-disable-emoji-from-being-entered-in-android-edittext/26297861)

but no luck.

Can someone please help to look into this issue since this is a must have functionality for us.

Comment: You could downloaded an older version of gboard from apkpure and installed it, this is the gboard version Gboard the Google Keyboard_v8.8.8.276639079-release-arm64-v8a_apkpure.com.apk. 

**Edit:** after installing the older version go the play store and look for gboard and turn off auto update

Answer (score 0):

Can you try below code on your EditText?

```
private void disableEmojiInTitle() {
InputFilter emojiFilter = new InputFilter() {
    @Override
    public CharSequence filter(CharSequence source, int start, int end, Spanned dest, int dstart, int dend) {
        for (int index = start; index < end - 1; index++) {
            int type = Character.getType(source.charAt(index));

            if (type == Character.SURROGATE) {
                return "";
            }
        }
        return null;
    }
};
editText.setFilters(new InputFilter[]{ emojiFilter });
```

}

you can add below type as well to exclude other symbols also

```
type==Character.OTHER_SYMBOL
```

Answer (score 0):

To disable emoji button on Samsung default soft keyboard use the below

```
yourEditText.setPrivateImeOptions("disableEmoticonInput=true;");
```

the flag for other keyboards is not so much known so it could be difficult.